# How does a device get automatically the receive address from another device to send data to it?

Tags: transaction, tangle, address

When a device A wants to send some data to device B, how does device A know the receive address from device B? Has to be there another protocol for that purpose?

Comment: Presentation of an interesting use case regarding transaction between a car and a charging station. Completely based on tangle : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTx0E6cT9X8&feature=youtu.be&t=2h49m15s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide an IOTA based service, considering the receiving address has to change on every withdrawal?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/570/how-to-provide-an-iota-based-service-considering-the-receiving-address-has-to-c)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment: Yes, because you don't know the address. Without the address you can't send another wallet messages. No messages or whatever. I would recommend to use gRPC or something similar. Simple reason why: It's fast and HTTP2.