# How to get the sender address from an IOTA transfer

Tags: transaction, iri-node, address, iri-legacy-api

When calling the API with `iota.api.getAccountData(receiveSeed, function(e, accountData)`, the transfer objects I see contain a field called "address" which contains the received address. I would like to also get the address of the sender for zero value transactions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero value transactions don't have a sender address. If you wan't to get them for value transactions you can get them through the input of the bundle which had that transaction.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I'm trying to do a PoC of this answer on a different question. https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/575/1382
In this example the users are sending their new addresses to eachother using the tangle, but in order for this to work I need some kind of reference to the sender address to verify that they are the correct person.

Comment: You can use MAM for this since in MAM you are the only one that is allowed to post to your stream. I know the wallet team is also researching into this. Not sure how far they are pursuing it tho.