# Why do transactions in a bundle need to be chained via trunkTransaction?

Tags: bundles

I'm trying to understand the inner workings of a bundle and its consequences.

From what I’ve read so far, transactions of a bundle are chained by the `trunkTransaction` of each transaction in the bundle pointing to the next transaction in the bundle. Why is this needed? There already is a `bundle` field in the transaction data structure and an index. Is this required to facilitate efficient traversal of transactions belonging to a bundle?

If `trunkTransaction` is used to chain transactions, how exactly does this work with the requirement to approve *two* transactions returned by `getTransactionsToApprove`?

In essence, I'm asking for the pseudo code / steps to craft a bundle and attach its transactions.

I first ask for two transactions to approve. I’ll then add the first as the `branchTransaction` of the first transaction of my (new) bundle. But what about the second? I cannot add it as the `trunkTransaction` because I’ll need that to build the chain.

Comment: related : https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-is-an-iota-bundle/936#936

Comment: @ben75 Thanks for the cross link. I am aware of the cheat sheet but it does not answer my question. getTransactionsToApprove returns two transactions, however, trunkTransaction will always be used / blocked / occupied to build the bundle chain. So I can only use branchTransaction and hence only approve one of the two transactions returned by getTransactionsToApprove. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question precisely. What do you mean by "blocked". The "2 transactions to approve" will be the branch and trunk (or trunk and branch) of the first transaction in your bundle. The trunk of the second transaction of your bunble must be the first transaction in your bundle. The branch transaction of the second tx in the bundle should be latest milestone. I don't see why one is "blocked". Maybe share some code ?

Comment: I assumed, that I need to getTransactionsToApprove for *every* Single transaction in my bundle. So you are saying that I request two transactions to approve *per bundle*, include their hashes as branch and trunk of the first transaction in my bundle and have the trunk of all subsequent transactions in my bundle point to their respective previous ones. And the branch of every transaction in the bundle except the first one should point to the latest milestone. Is this correct so far? The cheat sheet shows a different branch for the last transaction in the bundle, though.

Comment: please refer to this [question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/do-transactions-within-the-same-bundle-need-to-reference-specific-branch-and-tru) where a future change in the bundle construct (with respect to its trunk and branch) is announced by CfB which is in line with the "1 confirms 2" convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the code (in the Java library) and here is how it creates a bundle.

Let's say that *tip0* and *tip1* are the 2 tips to approve.

The last transaction in the bundle (transaction with highest bundle index) will use

- *tip0* as trunk-transaction
- *tip1* as branch-transaction

All other transactions in bundle will use

- the next transaction in bundle as trunk-transaction (i.e. transaction at index *i* will use transaction at index *i+1*)
- *tip0* as branch-transaction

Comment: But then the cheat sheet is wrong, or?

Comment: The cheat sheet represent the particular case where tip0 is the last milestone that leads to some confusion

Comment: @ben75 Your answer here is enlightening. When you write "First transaction in bundle" you mean the transaction with highest index in the bundle, don't you?

Comment: @drclink yes. I change my post accordingly to reflect bundle index.

Answer (score 0):

A visual representation and more in-depth-explanation can be found in this blog post:

https://medium.com/@louielu/in-depth-explanation-of-how-iota-making-a-transaction-with-picture-8a638805f905

[image: visual graph]