# Do transactions within the same bundle need to reference specific branch and trunk hashes?

Tags: transaction, bundles, branch, trunk

When adding a new transaction, I get two "random" other transactions to use as my branch and trunk.

But if I have several transactions in a bundle, does each one get their own random two? Or should *transaction 2* in the bundle reference *transaction 1*? And only the *0th transaction* in the bundle uses real random *not-this-bundle transactions*?

Here are docs on the subject, but I'm not sure I'm understanding this right:

https://domschiener.gitbooks.io/iota-guide/content/chapter1/bundles.html

> A unique feature of bundles is that the transactions are identified
>   via the bundle hash, but also via the trunkTransaction . What this
>   means is that the tail transaction (index 0), references in the
>   trunkTransaction the transaction hash at index: 1 , index 1 references
>   (and approves) index 2 and so on. This makes it possible to get the
>   full bundle of transactions from just a tail transaction by traversing
>   down the trunk transaction.

Comment: check out [this question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-is-an-iota-bundle) There is a beautiful bundle cheat sheet there which explains a bundle structure.

Answer (score 4):

A bundle consisting of N transactions can reference 2*N completely different transactions (almost half of them will belong to the bundle). The chain of trunkTransaction references must form the correct bundle, branchTransaction fields can reference tails (transactions with currentIndex = 0) of any other bundles.

Current implementation of the tip selection algorithm returns only 2 transactions to reference though, this is why now we have the currently observed picture.

Comment: So in the future a bundle that has N transactions will confirm N + 1 other transactions, am I right?

Comment: Yes. (This part is only for passing the character limit.)

Comment: Cool, thanks! (This part is also for passing the character limit)

Comment: N tx will confirm 2*N other tx of which (N-1) internally and (N+1) externally. Beautiful!

Answer (score 3):

I found the cheat sheet to be somewhat misleading as it assumes, that one tip to be confirmed is the latest solid milestone. You'll find a precise answer [here](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/953/why-do-transactions-in-a-bundle-need-to-be-chained-via-trunktransaction/992?noredirect=1#comment1098_992). I had the exact same conceptual question. Make sure you read all comments!

Answer (score 3):

They do, and this schema shows how **TX(currentIndex, lastIndex)**:

[image]

Taken from [this](https://blog.louie.lu/2018/01/08/in-depth-explanation-of-how-iota-making-a-transaction/) nice article.

Comment: The „trunkTip“ where all the branchTransaction fields in this schema point to, should be labeled „tail (index == 0) of other bundle“ instead of „trunk tip“, or? I think there is no such thing as a „trunk tip“ and the labeling is slightly confusing.

Comment: Then the “branch tip” could also be labeled “tail of another bundle” (‘TX(0,n)’). I think the labelling was supposed to show how, from a bundle perspective, other tx are referenced. I agree that naming can be somewhat confusing, since multiple branch and trunk references point towards a trunk tip.

Comment: My point is: A bundle comprises of multiple transactions with each having a `trunkTransaction` field, while a bundle has exactly one `tail`. IMHO, being as precise as possible here will help reducing confusion.

Comment: @ralf I have updated the image accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

okay I think I can answer my own question with this data:

`bundle/DFZCQK
  transaction/VYWRBV
    RZKOLU
    MJOTMK
  transaction/RZKOLU
    USOBTT
    MJOTMK
  transaction/USOBTT
    H9OOFC
    MJOTMK
  transaction/H9OOFC
    MJOTMK
    HBDVJA`

bundle DFZCQK has 4 transactions: [VYWRBV, RZKOLU, USOBTT, H9OOFC]

tx0 points to RZKOLU (in) and MJOTMK (out)

tx1 points to USOBTT (in) and MJOTMK (out)

tx2 points to H9OOFC (in) and MJOTMK (out)

tx3 points to MJOTMK (out) and HBDVJA (out)

from https://thetangle.org/bundle/DFZCQKAECRLLVZFCHFWVCWUGXGIZ9U9GCWPJLNSGWFCISOYETEITZCQWEDASSHRKCSVOTBZBV9LUGVDFD

The short answer is, within a bundle you are creating, you might as well approve your own transactions with each other and then go out to some txs outside your bundle at the very end.

Then more info is nonce of each tx:

```
MA999IWC9999999999999999999
9Z9999PF9999999999999999999
PA9999XG9999999999999999999
VA999IVE9999999999999999999
```