# "Multi-signature wallet" from Bitfinex

Tags: wallet, bitfinex

I saw that Bitfinex announced that they have updated their own *multi-signature* wallet. Why do they need to do this, is this something that official wallet API doesn't support?

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Multisignature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Smidgen](http://blog.bitfinex.com/tutorial/smidgen-iota-multisignature-wallet/) (aka the Bitfinex wallet) supports two features not available in the [official wallet](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/releases) :

- multi-signature wallet
- crafting bundles with [multiple recipients](https://medium.com/bitfinex/smidgen-development-update-an-iota-multisignature-wallet-63e61b396bfd)

This wallet is just a client to easily use existing features of the tangle:

- multi-signature is at the core of flash channels.
- transfers with multiple recipients was from the start in [IOTA's bundle design](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-is-an-iota-bundle)